# CSS, Confused about @media with classes

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to take my first forray into using "responsive" css, and I am working with this new `@media` ....... thing... and I am having a big of trouble understanding some of it. I have read up on it on multiple websites to form my code, and it isn't doing what I expected it to do, so I am getting more frustrated.

I basically have a place in text where, under normal circumstances, I want it to be `font-size: 64px;`, but if the screen gets very small (`480px`), I want it to be downsized to like `24px;`. I added some other ridiculous properties to make sure I am actually getting the different result, but I am quite confused still.

So this was my approach...

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
    .name {
        color: green;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
        font-size: 24px;
      }
}

.name {
   font-size: 64px;
}


<span class="name">This is a really long name</span>
```

So I expected that when this runs, it will have the normal `.name` class, and if the resolution dips to `480px` or thinner, it will go to the other one. Is this completely wrong? Because this is not what is happening for me.

Comment: You've got your condition backward. You have it set up for .name to kick in if it is LARGER than 480px.

Comment: I hope that Comic Sans is just a joke!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.name` selector within the media query has the same [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) as the `.name` selector *after* the media query. Because of this, the later `.name` selector will take precedence.

Simply changing the order will fix the issue:

```
.name {
   font-size: 64px;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
    .name {
        color: green;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
        font-size: 24px;
      }
}
```

If you'd like the styles within the media query to take effect when the screen is `480px` or thinner, you should be using the `max-width` media query:

```
.name {
   font-size: 64px;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .name {
        color: green;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
        font-size: 24px;
      }
}
```

Comment: god I feel so stupid. Yes, this was so simple. I am sorry, it has been a terrible morning. I feel like a complete moron.

Comment: @Ciel Always place the defaults first and alter the value inside the media queries.